# if there is a way to structure the code so that it is easier to reason about

Tags: c++

There is an array that contains attributes for another array. In the first cycle, it gets an index that is used to get the second index, and then used to update the first index.
Reasoning about this code is HARD because the indicies are self modifying.

I ' m asking if there is a way to structure the code so that it is easier to reason about. And depending what these arrays are used for there may not be.

```
int table[3][3] {
        { 1,1,1 },
        { 2,2,2 },
        { 1,1,1 }
    };

int arr[2][3] {
        { 0,1,2 },
        { 1,2,0 }
    };
```

cycle 1

```
int& A = arr[0][1], // 1 
   & B = arr[1][A]; // 2

A = table[A][B]; // 2
```

cycle 2

```
A = arr[0][1], // 2 
B = arr[1][A]; // 0

A = table[A][B]; // 1
```

cycle ...

Comment: Could you describe more clearly, what exactly this program does?

Comment: names are utterly important. Neither `table` nor `arr` tell anything about what those variables are, and single letter variables names should be banned for anything that spans across more than 2-3 lines of code

Comment: Cigien is asking the right question, but unclear. Clearer: We can almost certainly structure the code simpler, if we understood the problem that you're trying to solve, and thus the limitations and names of the various subcomponents. Please describe why you need `arr`, and then we can tell you how to structure it to be more clear.

Comment: Continuing on from Mooning Duck, you want some domain-specific variable names... what does `arr` represent in the problem this program is trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

From what you show,

- `table` is unmodified,
- `arr` is modified by existing value from `arr` or from `table`, so only by 0, 1, 2.

You have at most 3**6 (729) valid states and with deterministic transition.

So your total cycle length is at most 729.

If you create the array of the full cycle, you probably might reason easily.

Here we have only 3 states:

```
0 1 2  
1 2 0

  |
  v

0 1 2         0 2 2 
1 0 0   <->   1 0 0
```